# Hit Detection using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, canvas

I am a beginner who started to write some code several months ago.

So far,I already build a calculator using Javascript,HTML,and CSS.
Now,Im trying to make a platformer game using Javascript and HTML.

So,I already set up the player,obstacles,canvas,frames.and game over function.But I can't figure how hit detection works.

So,Im trying to do this:

```
this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {

    //Declaring all the player and the obstacles position!
    
    //Player!
    var myLeft = this.x;
    var myRight = this.x + (this.width);
    var myTop = this.y;
    var myBottom = this.y + (this.height);

    //Obstacles!
    var otherLeft = otherobj.x;
    var otherRight = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var otherTop = otherobj.y;
    var otherBottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);

    //Crash variables!
    var crash = true;

    if(
       //Checking the player location!
       (myBottom < otherTop) || 
       (myTop > otherBottom) || 
       (myRight < otherLeft) || (jump=true) ||
       (myLeft > otherRight) || (jump=true)
      )
     {
       /*
        If the player cordinates 
        is not touching the obstacles cordinate,
        crash is not happening/false.
       */

       crash = false;
     }

     if(
        (myTop == otherBottom) ||
        (myBottom == otherTop) || (jump=false)||
        (myLeft == otherRight) || (jump=false) ||
        (myRight == otherLeft) || (jump=false)
       )
     {
        crash = false;
     }

     return crash;
}
```

Before I write the second if statement,the player always freeze mid-air after dodging the obstacles.I know why the freeze happened,because the statement:

`(myRight < otherLeft)`

So,to do this I set up the jump variables.

```
var jump;

if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[32]) {myGamePiece.speedY = -2;} {jump=true} //jumping
if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[83]) {myGamePiece.speedY = 1; }
//going down

//Left and right!
if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[65]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -2; } // moving left
if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[68]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 1; } //moving right
```

And then I write the second if statement:

```
if(
    (myTop == otherBottom) ||
    (myBottom == otherTop) || (jump=false)||
    (myLeft == otherRight) || (jump=false) ||
    (myRight == otherLeft) || (jump=false)
  )
  {
    crash = false;
  }
```

After I write the second if statement,no more freeze,but the obstacles is like a ghost.

Full code:https://codepen.io/ratpipe/pen/PoprLzV

Comment: The code that immediately follows `//Checking the player location!` appears to have a problem. Was it your intention to _assign_ `true` to `jump` or was it your intention to _check if jump is true_ ? The same pattern follows in the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

`jump` variable is not needed. You can just check if rectangles have collided by checking if there is no gap between them. Found the following logic in Mozilla's web docs ([2D collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)).

```
if(
  myLeft < otherRight &&
  myRight > otherLeft &&
  myTop < otherBottom &&
  myBottom > otherTop )
{
  crash = true;
}
```

You need to add your initial `myObstacle` in `myObstacles` - `myObstacles.push(myObstacle);` before the game starts, for your game logic to check it here:

```
for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
  if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
    myGameArea.stop();
    return;
  }
}
```